# How do I make NodeList or array appear in the console?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the inputs in my code appear as a NodeList but when I look in the console it just says "undefined" for the line that contains `console.log(value);`
Here's what I have:

```
    var id = "word" + i;
    var input = document.querySelector("input#" + id);
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    var value = inputs.value;
    console.log(value);
```

Comment: `console.log(input)` and `console.log(inputs)` directly

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this, Because document.querySelectorAll() give values in array.

```js
var id = "word" + i;
var input = document.querySelector("input#" + id);
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach((val, index)=>{
console.log(val.value); 
}
)
```